# Is "divergent popularities" an acceptable phrase?

Tags: expressions, grammatical-number

Let's say we have two silent films released in the same year. One went on to become a classic, and the other one fell into oblivion. Should I refer to the "divergent popularities" or the "divergent popularity" of the two films? I know that the plural of popularity does exist, but it sounds a bit awkward in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's understandable, but I would stumble over it in reading, even more with the plural *popularities* than with the singular.

I suggest *divergent levels of popularity*.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather say ***divergent paths*** since popularity is the thing one of your movies actually lacks.

> *Two divergent paths* are moving in opposite directions — away from each other. ([Yourdict](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/divergent#:%7E:text=Two%20divergent%20paths%20are%20moving,a%20path%20or%20a%20standard.))

If the context is clear, then it will be obvious that *paths* is referring to the way in which it was received by the public.

Comment: I find _paths_ a very strange word in this context. If I read about two films taking divergent paths, I would suppose that this was about the different approaches the makers had taken. I don't think it would occur to me that it was about the different ways in which they were received subsequently.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question. Let’s start with the etymology of *diverge*

> [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/diverge)
> diverge (v.) 1660s,
> “move or lie in different directions from a common point" (the opposite of converge), from Modern Latin divergere "go in different directions," from assimilated form of dis- "apart" (see dis-) + vergere "to bend, turn, tend toward" (from PIE root *wer- (2) "to turn, bend").
> Originally a term in optics. The general or figurative senses of "become or be separated from another; differ from a typical form" emerged by mid-19c.

An important feature of this history is that “di” refers to “apart” rather than the superficially inviting “two or twice”.

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/di)
> di:
> two or twice: used with some adjectives and nouns

Consequently we have:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divergent)
> *divergent*:
> 1a : moving or extending in different directions from a common point : diverging from each other
> *divergent paths*
> b : differing from each other or from a standard
> *the divergent interests of capital and labor*

This makes clear that *divergent* often applies to two or more items, not to one. In that case, the items are plural: in your case, *popularities* (which may be of many sorts: youthful or elderly audiences, fetish or fringe audiences, etc).

*Divergent* may also apply to a singular noun or noun phrase. Examples are a divergent spray, a divergent explosion, a divergent radioactive decay. In these examples the noun or NP is inherently something with an implied common point of departure (M-W meaning 1a above). Does *popularity* have a similar common point of divergence? It is hard to define what that point might be so I suggest the singular usage is inappropriate.

In brief, I argue for **popularities**

Comment: Downvoting two reasoned answers (that offer different arguments) for no reason gives the PO no information or reason and is merely careless and unhelpful negativity.